# JavaScript: Display Multiple Divs on Single Button Click

Tags: javascript

I need to show a series of `<div>` elements one at a time when the user clicks a button. They start out hidden using `<div style="display:none">`. There are a total of 11 `<div>` tags each with different "id" from `id="dt-1"` to `id="dt-11"`

Here's the code I have now:

```js
function adddt() {
    var count;
    for(count=1;count<6;count++)
    {
        document.getElementById('dt-'+count+'').style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

```html
<div id='dt-1'>
<label>Destination 1</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-2' style="display:none;">
<label>Destination 2</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-3' style="display:none;">
<label>Destination 3</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-4' style="display:none;">
<label>Destination 4</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-5' style="display:none;">
<label>Destination 5</label>
<input type="text">
<input type="number">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="adddt()" value="add more destinations">
```

As you can see, when you click the button it shows all of the `<div>`s,
not one at a time. Each click should only add a single `<div>`, not all of them.

1. First click - show `<div id='dt-2'>`
2. Second click - show `<div id='dt-3'>`
3. ... and so on.

Comment: You need to use jQuery or plain Javascript, PHP has nothing to do with this

Comment: "1 click show 2 click show and so on." So you mean sequentially show each dt? First click would should `dt-1`, fourth click would show `dt-4`? What should happen when you click it 6 or 12 times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this, use a variable where you store the current id and each time you increment it by 1 :

```js
var count = 2;
var countMax = 5;

function adddt() {
  if(count > countMax)
    return;
  document.getElementById('dt-' + count + '').style.display = 'block';
  count++;
}
```

```html
<div id='dt-1'>
  <label>Destination 1</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-2' style="display:none;">
  <label>Destination 2</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-3' style="display:none;">
  <label>Destination 3</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-4' style="display:none;">
  <label>Destination 4</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
</div>

<div id='dt-5' style="display:none;">
  <label>Destination 5</label>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="number">
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="adddt()" value="add more destinations">
```

Comment: this is the solution i really needed it help me a lot, @temani-afif thanks for the help brother.